# Active pattern broken in F# 3.0

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2012, f#-3.0, active-pattern

This active pattern compiles with F# 2.0:

```ml
let (|Value|_|) value = // 'a -> 'T option
  match box value with
  | :? 'T as x -> Some x
  | _ -> None
```

but, in F# 3.0, emits the error:

> Active pattern '|Value|_|' has a result type containing type variables that are not determined by the input. The common cause is a [sic] when a result case is not mentioned, e.g. 'let (|A|B|) (x:int) = A x'. This can be fixed with a type constraint, e.g. 'let (|A|B|) (x:int) : Choice = A x'

I tried:

```ml
let (|Value|_|) value : 'T option = ...
```

and:

```ml
let (|Value|_|) (value: 'U) = ...
```

How can it be fixed?

Environments: Visual Studio 2012 (RTM) and FSI v11.0.50727.1

EDIT: Here's a simpler repro:

```ml
let (|X|) x = unbox x
```

Comment: Works fine for me, Visual Studio 2012 RC updated, `Microsoft (R) F# 3.0 Interactive build 11.0.50522.1`. Seeing the error, I still think it should work (as it does). The example in the error (`let (|A|B|) (x:int) = A x`) does indeed present the error you have posted.

Comment: `F# 2.0 Interactive build 4.0.40219.1` gives exactly the same results.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific about the environment. I've updated the question.

Comment: I'll try to get my hands on the RTM version from my university, but until then I cannot help you :(

Comment: It's only a day old and still has the 'new software' smell, so no worries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a bug in the F# 2.0 compiler where the compiler did incorrect analysis and bad code generation for certain Active Patterns with free type variables in the result; a simple repro is

```
let (|Check|) (a : int) = a, None
//let (|Check|) (a : int) = a, (None : int option)

let check a = 
    match a with
    | Check (10, None) -> System.Console.WriteLine "10"
    | Check (20, None) -> System.Console.WriteLine "20"

check 10
check 20
```

which generates a weird warning at compile-time and compiles into seemingly incorrect code.  I am guessing that our attempt to fix this bug (and restrict some crazy cases) in F# 3.0 also broke some legal code as collateral damage of the fix.

I'll file another bug, but for F# 3.0, it sounds like you'll need to use one of the workarounds mentioned in other answers.

Comment: Has this been fixed for F# 3.1?

Answer (score 3):

I did not install the new version yet, but I agree this looks a bit fishy. I guess there may be a good reason for this restriction, but your example in the other question seems quite compeling.

As a workaround, I think that adding a witness parameter (that is not used, but hints what the type of the result is going to be) could work:

```
let (|Value|_|) (witness:unit -> 'T) value : 'T option =
  match box value with 
  | :? 'T as x -> Some x 
  | _ -> None
```

Of course, this makes the use a bit uglier, because you need to come up with some argument. In the above, I used witness of type `unit -> 'T`, hoping that the following might compile:

```
let witness () : 'T = failwith "!"

match box 1 with 
| Value witness 1 -> printfn "one"
```

If that does not work, then you can probably try using witness parameter of type `'T` (but then you have to provide an actual function, rather than just a generic function).

Comment: Thanks for the workaround. I can't imagine a "good reason" for breaking something that works in a previous version (and is useful). :-)

Comment: The workaround in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11990910/162396) (inspired by kvb's) to a follow-up question doesn't require the `witness` parameter and retains the original usage.

Answer (score 2):

for the sake of completeness, one more workaround:

```
type Box<'R> = Box of obj

let (|Value|_|) ((Box x) : Box<'R> ) : 'R option =
  match x with 
  | :? 'R as x -> Some x 
  | _ -> None 

let check t =
    match Box t with
    | Value 1 -> printfn "one"
    | Value 2 -> printfn "two"

check 1 // one
check 2 // two
```

however it still will suffer from the problem mentioned by @kvb in [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989377/pattern-combining-type-test-and-literal). Personally I'll prefer @kvb's version with parameterized active pattern.

Answer (score 0):

See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11990500/82959) to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11989377/pattern-combining-type-test-and-literal) for some thoughts on how to work around the issue and one reason that such active patterns might be undesirable.  I'm not sure whether the breaking change was intended.